# Combine Wordpress categories array with another one

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I am trying to achieve somenthing that is beyond my php knowledge and cant seem to get around it.

What I want to do is assign a list of colours for each category of wordpress as a class.

Eg: My categories are "cat 1", "cat 2" and "cat 3"
My colours are "red", "green" and "blue"

When I print get_categories each categoy should get an individual class and style, so cat 1 would get a red background, cat 2 a green one and cat 3 blue.

More over, I would like to be able to add a lot of colours (for instance 25) and if there are 10 categories, then use only the first 10 colours.

Answer (score 0):

in your theme, you could use the [post_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) output for the post categories together with the output of [the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) within the loop to get the effect;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category

example (for simplicity assuming each post only has one category, needs to be within the loop):

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
<h3 class="entry-title"><span class="media-type"><?php the_category(' '); ?></span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<!--more post output-->
</div>
```

and in the style.css:

```
.category-cat1 span a { color: green; }
.category-othercatname span a { color: orange; }
```

more [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/category-colors-1)

Comment: Hi Marty, thanks for the reply. The thing is that I want it to be dynamic, meaning that I don't want to have to add each style specifically for each category.
With that solution I have to add every specific style (eg cat-101) and I want to have like 20 styles and those to be assigned to each category automatically.
For instance: My css: #orange-cat { color: orange; } #blue-cat { color: blue; } #cyan-cat { color: cyan; } ETC
And then if in my site I have 1 cat, that will be orange and if in another site I have 2 cats, one will be orange and the other blue and so on for every site.